# add a code to eclipse jvm configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, proxy, jvm, environment-variables

I have 3 lines of code, I need to add them to Eclipse JVM configuration in order to not having to write them everytime in every program I develop. These are the three lines:

```
System.getProperties().put("proxySet", "true");
System.getProperties().put("proxyHost","prxoy.com");
System.getProperties().put("proxyPort", "8080");
```

Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `Preferences`, then navigate the tree to `Java -> Installed JREs`.

From there you can then `Edit` your chosen/default JRE and add your System Properties by entering them into the `Default VM Arguments` field, e.g.:

```
-DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=prxoy.com -DproxyPort=8080
```

Comment: @AouesGuesmi Yes the format is `-Dkey=value -Dkey=value` etc... Take a look at the [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-add_new_jre.htm) for clarification - there are screen shots included.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can configure proxy host and port under **Network Connections**

```
Preferences >> General >> Network Connections
```

Select **Active provider** as 'Manual' and update/edit the proxy host and port.